# Can I include notes in reports?

Tags: reporting, notes

I want to report on the leads and other custom objects which have notes associated with it.

Comment: Do you get your answer?I am looking for solution on Opportunity object.

Answer (score 3):

There has been a step forward regarding reporting on notes.

There is a lot of excitement going on with the Lightning Experience.
However enhancements for taking notes have also taken place.
There is a new version of Notes that was published with Winter 16 and you can report on them.

- Salesforce help doc on reporting on New Notes: [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_create_report.htm&language=th)
- Salesforce doc on differences between the New Notes and the Old Notes: [link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_differences.htm&language=th)
- Salesforce help doc on setting up the New Notes: [link](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=notes_admin_setup.htm&siteLang=en_US)
- See the Winter 16 Release Notes regarding "Notes": [link](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_sales_notes.htm#rn_sales_notes)

The New Notes are being handled as Files objects and therefore from a reporting stand point, it looks like it lacks in providing the association between a note and an object.

[image]

Comment: When I create report type there is no object name 'File and Content Report' based on link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_create_report.htm&language=th  , but Note is available.Is there any reason why I could not see it?

Comment: @unidha, you need to remove the fields that gets added by default when creating a new report except the ones listed in the link you have referred to. Salesforce excludes the note records when fields like 'Downloaded By' are added to the report.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to report on Notes.  There is an Idea, [Reporting on Notes & Attachments](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhNAAS.) that requests this feature.

You could export the data and report on it outside of Salesforce, build a custom page, query for it via the API from an outside app, etc., but there is no native report functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field on Lead (or on whatever object you want) and populate that field to true or false via a trigger when a note is created or deleted. Then you can create a report for all leads having custom field value equals to true.

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce link on creating reports has changed from above and it took a bit of digging to find it again, so posting here: [Create a report on Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319978&type=1)